# Why do ISO files on Mac OS X created using an app always change the date to 1 January 2001?

Tags: dmg, iso, archive-utility

I downloaded [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) and the app works well, but when I created a test .iso file from some photos saved on an iPhone (a copy of the folder I placed on the Desktop), I noticed this unusual thing:

The JPEG files all retained the modification date, but their creation date was set to 1 January 2001 00:00

When I created a DMG file, the JPEG files kept both the creation and modification dates.

Why does this happen with file modification dates? I'd created the folder for cross-OS compatibility, since I was intending to send it as an email attachment (the folder was only around 12MB worth of files).

Is this usual with archive utility type apps for the Mac when converting a folder to ISO?